# Intelephense false error - Laravel\Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am working with Livewire via Laravel. Whenever I try to use #[Rule], I get a red squiggly error undefined Type intelephense (P1009).

Again here is an example of my code:

```
use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;

// Rule has a red squiggly all over it
#[Rule('image|max:2048')]
```

Comment: do you have `public $file;` under it?

Comment: Yes I do have public $file underneath it

Comment: is the error from `Intelephense`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was stuck on Livewire version 2. That's why I had all of these things pop up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).